# Difference Between GitOps And Traditional CI/CD

Tags: git, kubernetes, continuous-integration, continuous-deployment

In normal kubernetes CI/CD process , following process occurs :

- clone code from git
- build and push docker image
- update kubernetes deployment with updated code

According to gitops definition

*GitOps is a new approach to Continuous Deployment that leverages Git as a single source of truth for declarative infrastructure and applications, providing both revision and change control. With GitOps, a system is run by submitting pull requests (and subsequent merges) to achieve the desired state of the system represented in a Git repository*

what my understanding of gitops is , when you update anything in git (as this is the source of truth) , the desired state of kubernetes changes to the latest one and the latest code is deployed.

**End Result of traditional CI/CD without gitops**:  new code is deployed as kubernetes deployment

**End Result of gitops**: new code is deployed as kubernetes deployment

I am unable to figure the difference . sorry if it sounds weird to you. But I am kinda new and exploring gitops .

Comment: GitOps in k8s context usually assumes that you use a specialized GitOps tool, such as ArgoCD or Flux, see my write-up about working implementation on a toy project: https://itnext.io/building-kubernetes-cicd-pipeline-with-github-actions-argocd-and-reliza-hub-e7120b9be870

Comment: @taleodor so you are saying that just using gitops tool make CI CD a gitops?

Comment: Close to that. More specifically, GitOps assumes near-realtime reactivity to the changes in your repository. So that you eliminate the gap between the state of your repository and the state of your environments. This is hard to achieve without specialized tools.

Answer (score 1):

GitOps is nothing but extending CI/CD principles beyond application code: to infra code. Simple. You can think of using Git as source of truth that combines with Terraform (provisioning), Ansible (config mgmt) and Kubernetes (orchestration) as an example ...in order to achieve the goal of keeping Git as 1:1 reflection of your infra. It's nothing new and do not be worried about such fancy terms...

Comment: Read more here https://about.gitlab.com/topics/gitops/

Answer (score 0):

CICD focuses on the whole chain:

- You checkin your code
- Code get tested
- Container created and uploaded
- Container get deployed
- Container get tested

Plus many other steps in between. That’s why it is a continuous integration & deployment. You also could say, an end to end process.

GitOps don’t care about your code, the docker build or so. It purely focus on keeping your apps updated (deployment part), in extreme form with Progressive Delivery fully automated with traffic shifting and health checks, auto fall back etc.

Beside this you have other small details which sometimes matter like push vs pull, cluster autonomy, separation of concerns.

Comment: but how is app going to be updated? once the code is updated ...right?
so eventually you need to build docker in order to updated application

Comment: you can have two triggers for the update, ether the deployment information or configuration change or you have an update of the container. Flux or ArgoCD can react to both, mostly in combination and do a rolling or progressive update.

Answer (score -1):

Short answer - GitOps is a framework, CI/CD is a process!

GitOps aims at leveraging Git as a source of truth and empowers developers to perform IT operations. It automates Git workflow with continuous integration and continuous delivery (CI/CD). Let me take an example here - I have a kubernetes cluster for which I have CI/CD pipelines setup for automation, yet we used to see incidents where someone made a manual change to the application version directly on cluster(happens everywhere!). We leveraged GitOps to have a declaration of my cluster so that everytime someone made manual changes, it would override and bring it back to it's original stated declared in Git (done using GitOps agent like Flux).